# Custom post type (Jigoshop): unexpected value for $category_id (via $term->term_taxonomy_id) on live server

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-taxonomy-queries, jigoshop

I have hacked together a function to spit out the category description for a Jigoshop custom post type, along with its associated image. (The product_cat image field is implemented by the Jigoshop plugin).

It works locally, but on my server the image is not always being found — the returned $category_id seems to be out by 1 for some (but not all) of the products.

```
function cyclelux_brand_info() {
function get_the_category_bytax( $id = false, $tcat = 'category' ) {
    $categories = get_the_terms( $id, $tcat );
    if ( ! $categories )
    $categories = array();
    $categories = array_values( $categories );
    foreach ( array_keys( $categories ) as $key ) {
        _make_cat_compat( $categories[$key] );
    }
    // Filter name is plural because we return alot of categories
    return apply_filters( 'get_the_categories', $categories );
}
// TODO: tidy this up, won't work if product assigned to multiple categories
$cat = get_the_category_bytax($post->ID,'product_cat');
// print_r(get_the_terms( $id, 'product_cat' ));
// print_r($cat);
foreach ( $cat as $term ) {
       $category_description = $term->description;
       $category_id = $term->term_taxonomy_id;
}
// echo "category_id = " . $category_id;
// echo "<br>jigoshop_product_cat_image = " . jigoshop_product_cat_image($category_id)["image"];
// echo "<br>jigoshop_product_cat_thumb_id = " . jigoshop_product_cat_image($category_id)["thumb_id"];
echo "<hr>";
echo "<div class=\"section group brand-info\">
    <div class=\"col span_3_of_6 brand-logo\"></span><img src=\"" . jigoshop_product_cat_image($category_id)["image"] . "\"></div>
<div class=\"col span_3_of_6\">
<p class=\"xbrand-info\">" . $category_description . "</p>
</div>
</div>
<hr>";
}
```

Comment: (PS. Each product is only assigned a single category)

Answer (score 1):

For a Category landing page that only shows each 'product_cat' image that links to a separate page for each category, I have the following template enclosed.

It doesn't use `$term->term_taxonomy_id` but rather `$term->term_id`.  Not sure if it will help, but look it over for differences from what you have.

```
<?php
/**
 * Product taxonomy template
 */
?>

<?php global $wp_query; ?>

<?php get_header('shop'); ?>
<?php do_action('jigoshop_before_main_content'); ?>

<?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( $wp_query->query_vars['taxonomy'] ), $wp_query->query_vars['taxonomy'] ); ?>

<h1 class="page-title"><?php echo wptexturize($term->name); ?></h1>

<?php echo wpautop(wptexturize($term->description)); ?>

<?php
    $args = array(
        'orderby'       => 'name', 
        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'child_of'      =>  $term->term_id, 
    );
    $categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
?>

<?php if ( sizeof( $categories ) ) : ?>

    <div class="product-list">

        <ul>

            <?php foreach ( $categories as $category ) :

                $term = get_term_by( 'id', $category->term_id, 'product_cat' );
                if ( ! empty( $term )) :
                    $title = $term->name;
                    $thumb = jigoshop_product_cat_image( $term->term_id );
                    if ( $thumb['thumb_id'] )
                      $thumb_image = wp_get_attachment_image( $thumb['thumb_id'], 'shop_small' );
                    else
                      $thumb_image = jigoshop_get_image_placeholder( 'shop_small' );
                    ?>
                    <li class="product">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term->slug, 'product_cat' ); ?>" title="<?php echo $title; ?>">
                            <div class="image-wrap">
                                <?php echo $thumb_image; ?>
                                <span class="info-icon"></span>
                            </div>
                            <p><strong>
                                <?php echo ( strlen( $title ) > 70 ) ? substr( $title , 0, 70) . '...' : $title; ?>
                            </strong></p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

<?php else : ?>

    <?php jigoshop_get_template_part( 'loop', 'shop' ); ?>
    <?php do_action('jigoshop_pagination'); ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action('jigoshop_after_main_content'); ?>
<?php do_action('jigoshop_sidebar'); ?>
<?php get_footer('shop'); ?>
```